# Regularizing the constraints in fairlearn's ThresholdOptimizer

Tags: fairlearn

Is there a way to have a lambda regularizer value on the constraints in the ThresholdOptimizer? For instance if we want to create accuracy vs SPD curves I want to have different thresholds enforced on the SPD/accuracy constraints that would indicate their importance (maybe initially accuracy is more important then gradually SPD gains importance).

Answer (score 1):

Fairlearn maintainer here! [I can't comment on StackOverflow, so sadly these clarifying questions need to be in an "answer", but I'll update it once I understand your concern.]

What do you mean by SPD?

Can you describe a use case where it's clear what you mean by "initially accuracy is more important, then gradually SPD gains importance"? `ThresholdOptimizer` currently only supports the case where you satisfy your constraints 100%. One could think of ways to extend this to have some tolerance in constraint violation to improve the accuracy (or other performance measures).

You might have come across the built-in charts `fairlearn` provides for `ThresholdOptimizer`: https://fairlearn.org/v0.6.1/api_reference/fairlearn.postprocessing.html#fairlearn.postprocessing.plot_threshold_optimizer
The chart depends on your constraint, of course, but those may prove to be helpful in explaining how it arrived at the threshold(s).

If you have a concrete feature request feel free to open an issue directly in the repository as well! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By SPD I meant statistical parity difference (although it can be any other fairness measure as well). And exactly, I think you understood my question. I meant the exact thing as in extending the work on violating the constraint such that sometimes accuracy is more important sometimes fairness (something like the Pareto curves). For now I also used the interpolation_dict and _tradeoff_curve to reason about some of these thersholdings and tradeoffs as you suggested; however, I am not sure if this is the best way to go around solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I think it's an excellent question. If you want to pursue this further I'd suggest opening an issue on the [Fairlearn repository on GitHub](https://github.com/fairlearn/fairlearn) since it likely involves making changes to the existing code. I would be happy to help think through this sort of task.

If you're looking for a quicker way to get this I would suggest using something like `fairlearn.reductions.GridSearch`.

Comment: It outputs a whole bunch of models, and the best of them lie on the pareto curve showing the best trade-offs between the performance and fairness metrics of your choice. The plot in this section is an example that was generated with `GridSearch`. To get a full example I'd suggest looking at the usage of `GridSearch` in this notebook: https://fairlearn.org/v0.6.1/auto_examples/plot_grid_search_census.html